# move back to previous commit and delete current commit I am on

Tags: git

I have the following commits:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
ba69c7a4c4a642549e70319ccb1f7904893d6df1 ko added with currentCat and works
63e61d861923694944084e47ed613385d329a36a ko added seperate cat function
ad8be8da63e0381dfeb4a1db108021dd294b0556 init
$
```

I want to move back to my 2nd commit `63e6` and delete the `ba69` commit. how do I do this?

For my reference:

*how to show what commit I am on:*

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
ba69c7a4c4a642549e70319ccb1f7904893d6df1
$ git show | head -n 5
commit ba69c7a4c4a642549e70319ccb1f7904893d6df1
Author: Your Name <you@example.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 3 14:02:32 2016 +1300

    ko added with currentCat and works
```

**EDIT1**
as per below comment, reset and then commited again, this can be seen in the `git reflog`

```
$ git reflog
9522fd7 HEAD@{0}: commit: ko add the with to iterate through the currentCat
63e61d8 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to 63e61
ba69c7a HEAD@{2}: commit: ko added with currentCat and works
63e61d8 HEAD@{3}: commit: ko added seperate cat function
ad8be8d HEAD@{4}: clone: from https://github.com/HattrickNZ/ud989-cat-clicker-ko-starter
```

Comment: `git reset --hard 63e61` think this is what I want. [this] (http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#lostnfound) brings me back to the commit I want to be on and deletes the one I am currently on.

Comment: Who says that deletes the commit?  Check the reflog and you may be surprised.  What you did will remove the commit from your branch, but the commit is still in history.

Answer (score 1):

After `git reset --hard <commit>`, do `git push -f origin` to force push and permanently delete the commit from your repository history.

If you want to keep the commit in the repo history, use `git revert <commit>` to revert the commit you don't want.